# Ionicons, Bootstrap - Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, http-status-code-404, head

The browser console reminds me of several errors that I can not correct.

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

Here the files concerned with their correct position in the FTP:

- ../font/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css
- ../font/bootstrap/ionicons.ttf
- ../font/bootstrap/ionicons.woff

Here my code in the `<head>` section:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../../font/ionicons/ionicons.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../../font/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../../font/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css">
```

I have tried all the following declarations but nothing works:

- href="../font/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css"
- href="/font/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css"
- or href="//font/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css"

**Although this error message appears, Bootstrap and Ionicons are working correctly.** I want to correct this error for performance reasons.

Here the website concerned: http://www.chokala-tenerife.com

Do you have a solution to solve this problem?

Comment: If you only have two font files (the .ttf and the .woff file), the error comes from the css `@font-face` rule in ionicons.css, which tries to load an .eot file first.

Comment: Hello Mr Lister,
Thank you for your answer. Can you tell me what I have to do? Delete the .eot file? the .ttf and the .woff?