# Why my website is destructured on page load?

Tags: javascript, css

My site has serious structuring problems when loading pages ...
Here my [website](http://www.chokala-tenerife.com/)

You will see, if you click on a link, the website is going crazy:

[Screenshot of my website on page load](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CLGTp.jpg)

Thanks for your help,

Comment: Yet, there was not this problem before.
This is a theme I bought, here is the original theme: https://demo.proteusthemes.com/restaurant

Comment: Chrome 59 no-repo.

Comment: Also, your website is not loading your bootstrap css. 404. your link is like so `href="../../font/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css"` while your file path is `http://www.chokala-tenerife.com/font/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css`

Comment: This is the first question I asked on stackoverflow 4 months ago..:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43158130/ionicons-bootstrap-failed-to-load-resource-the-server-responded-with-a-statu

Bootstrap works but you're right, there is a 404 error. I tried to put your link but it's the same. I put "../../" because of the multilingual domains

Comment: You need to flush your cache in order to see if the error is resolved. Your current cache has this expiration date: `Mon, 30-Jul-2018 19:15:21 GMT`

Comment: I use a Cache Killer extension on Chrome, the 404 error is still here. I let the link you gave me in the header if you wanna check. Anyway, thank you for your help

Comment: The cache killer extension - or any other extension on your browser - only deletes the cached files from your browser's storage - locally - You pages are cached by your server and served when requested. You need to refresh those saved copies that your server has.

Comment: I flushed my cache but I still have the 404 (and Bootstrap is still correctly working)

Comment: Your links also don't declare what type of file it is. Browsers will try to read the file as a document. You need to add `type="text/css"` to your stylesheet links. so `<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.chokala-tenerife.com/font/bootstrap/css/bootstrap‌​.min.css">
` should be changed into something like this `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://www.chokala-tenerife.com/font/bootstrap/css/bootstrap‌​.min.css">
`

Answer (score 0):

It seems the `.push-pane__nav` div is sliding over and over, making a blink effect when clicking multiple links.

Maybe just remove the div or try setting `display: none`?

Comment: [I noticed that we see the links of the mobile nav quickly in the white zone (links are white)][3]

As you have seen, the big space that appears during the loading of the page let glimpse the links of my mobile-nav. So I tried to hide this links with this :

    @media (min-width: 991px) { .mobile-nav {display: none !important;} }

However the loading of the pages is still very dirty as you can see in the screenshot 3:

[Loading of the page without mobile nav..][4]

  [3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/YZoGA.jpg
  [4]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/bpc2k.png